# How to update resource through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

```
class Site < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
  has_one :metric
end

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And my post table has the signature:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :site, null: false
      t.bigint :post_id, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :posts, %i[site_id post_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Because a post `has_one` metric and because how my app works, I only have access to the `site_id` and `post_id`. I would like to know how can I create a route and controller that updates the `metric` of a post without knowing exactly the `id` of the metric (only through the `site_id` and `post_id`).

Thank you.

Comment: You can combine https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html on the model and https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for on the form to update the Metric associated to a Post

Comment: you can use nested forms from creating or updating associated models.